# Dotted line with FancyArrowPatch

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `python` and `matplotlib.pyplot` to generate a complex graphical output. I'd like to use a `dotted` linestyle in conjunction with `FancyArrowPatch` but failed to do so.

MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

style="Simple,head_width=4,head_length=8"
linestyle="dotted" # or "solid"
kw = dict(arrowstyle=style, linestyle=linestyle, color="b", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=1")
plt.gca().add_patch(patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,1), (1,1), **kw))
plt.savefig("MWE.pdf")
```

This generates the following image:

[image: Zoom of MWE.pdf]

However, I'd like to get something like:

[image: GIMPed version using linestyle solid]

**Question:** What do I have to change in my MWE to get the lower image?

Comment: I doubt it is possible, to easily change the linestyle of the FancyArrowPatch. This is really a patch in the sense of a polygon, consisting of 13 points which are connected by lines. If changing the linestyle you cannot change it for only part of the patch.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Do you know if it is possible to separate the full patch into two separate ones for which I could then specify different styles?

Comment: This thread answers the question very well: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17284

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in the comments, I doubt that it is possible, to easily change the linestyle of the FancyArrowPatch. This is really a patch in the sense of a polygon, consisting of 13 points which are connected by lines. If changing the linestyle you cannot change it for only part of the patch.

An option might indeed to split the patch into the arrow head and the tail. For the tail you would only take part of it and create a new line along those points. This line can be given its own linestyle. The head may stay a filled patch, for which you may choose a different linestyle.

You may get the path of the original arrow by `arrow.get_path()`. Note that this will fix the coordinates, i.e. all transforms of the arrow will be lost. Hence you need to make sure to do this only once the final axes limits and figure size have been set, and that if changing any of them later on will squeeze the arrow in an undesired manner.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path
import matplotlib.patches as patches


style="Simple,head_width=40,head_length=80"
kw = dict(arrowstyle=style, linestyle=None, lw=1,color="b",connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0.2")
arrow = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,1), (1,1), **kw)

plt.gca().add_patch(arrow)
plt.gca().axis([0,1.03,0,1.1])

def split_arrow(arrow, color_tail="C0",color_head="C0", 
                ls_tail="-", ls_head="-",lw_tail=1.5, lw_head=1.5):    
    v1 = arrow.get_path().vertices[0:3,:]
    c1 = arrow.get_path().codes[0:3]
    p1 = matplotlib.path.Path(v1,c1)
    pp1 = patches.PathPatch(p1, color=color_tail, linestyle=ls_tail, 
                            fill=False, lw=lw_tail)
    arrow.axes.add_patch(pp1)

    v2 = arrow.get_path().vertices[3:8,:]
    c2 = arrow.get_path().codes[3:8]
    c2[0] = 1
    p2 = matplotlib.path.Path(v2,c2)
    pp2 = patches.PathPatch(p2, color=color_head, lw=lw_head, linestyle=ls_head)
    arrow.axes.add_patch(pp2)
    arrow.remove()

split_arrow(arrow, color_tail="crimson",color_head="limegreen", 
                ls_tail="--", lw_tail=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative implementation is to split the arrow into two parts:

- arrow shaft (dotted line)
- arrow head (not dotted)

[I used this workaround](https://github.com/christiankral/EE.jl) to draw a dotted line phasor.

[image: Phasor diagram created by EE.jl]