# Matplotlib annotate dashed fancy arrow only on body, not head

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotate

The following code produces an arrow with a dashed contour line. I would like to keep the line between the two heads dashed, but not the one around the heads that I'd like to be plain.

Indeed, if the line and the patch colors are the same, the arrow's head is jagged.

I do not really know where to start on this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.annotate("", xy = (0.2,0.2), xytext = (0.8,0.8), arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle="<|-|>", shrinkA = 0, shrinkB = 0, linestyle = '--', mutation_scale = 30))
ax.annotate("", xy = (0.2,0.3), xytext = (0.9,0.8), arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle="<|-|>", shrinkA = 0, shrinkB = 0, linestyle = '--', mutation_scale = 30, color = 'r', linewidth = 2))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180328/pyplot-dotted-line-with-fancyarrowpatch/47205418#47205418)? Unfortunately, there is no easy solution to this.

Comment: I'am very bad at looking for answer it seems. Should I delete this question as it is completely the same question ?

Comment: You can,but don't need to. I now closed this as duplicate; so potentially someone using the same wording as you when searching for answers could be guided here and would then find the answer in the linked duplicate.