# Plotting part of FancyArrowPatch line in dashed style

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotate

I am trying to plot part of an `matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch` in a dashed style. Using this post [pyplot: Dotted line with FancyArrowPatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180328/pyplot-dotted-line-with-fancyarrowpatch/47205418#47205418), I managed to get quite close to it :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

plt.figure()

kw = dict(arrowstyle = '-', shrinkA = 0, shrinkB = 0, color = 'k', connectionstyle = "arc3, rad = -0.9" )
arrow = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((0, 0), (5, 3), **kw)
plt.gca().add_patch(arrow)
points = np.array([i[0] for i in arrow.get_path().iter_segments(curves = False)])
# arrow.remove()
a, = plt.plot(points[:-3,0], points[:-3,1])
plt.plot(points[-4:,0], points[-4:,1],  linestyle = '--', color = a.get_color())
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

To my understanding, the blue line does not match the black one because iter_segments() converts curves into straight lines with a density of point too low.

How should I do to get a better result ?

Comment: The linked answer uses a `PathPatch`, not a `plot`. The reason is that the points of the path are the pivots of Bezier curves. Therefore the curve itself will not touch them at all.

Comment: Oh right. Any hint about how to convert a bezier curve into a serie of points properly ? This is the only idea I had to plot this curve half plain line half dashed line.

Comment: Oh, due to the use of `curves = False`, the points should at least lie *on* the curve. The fact that they don't is due to the path being evaluated in display space, not in data space. You can check `plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")`. Hence, do you need the new arrow to follow the exact back curve, or is it more that it needs to be any curve.

Comment: I guess It could be any curve as soon as it respects the starting and ending point. Besides, I did not manage to make the points lie on the curve using `ax.transData` and `ax.transData.transform`. There is something I did not understand in this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate the Bezier curve that is produced by the arrow manually.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from scipy.special import binom

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

kw = dict(arrowstyle = '-', shrinkA = 0, shrinkB = 0, color = 'k', 
          connectionstyle = "arc3, rad = -0.9" )
arrow = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((0, 0), (5, 3), **kw)
ax.add_patch(arrow)


bernstein = lambda n, k, t: binom(n,k)* t**k * (1.-t)**(n-k)

def bezier(points, t=[0,1], num=200):
    N = len(points)
    t = np.linspace(*t, num=num)
    curve = np.zeros((num, 2))
    for i in range(N):
        curve += np.outer(bernstein(N - 1, i, t), points[i])
    return curve

verts = arrow.get_path().vertices
curve1 = bezier(verts, t=[0.0, 0.5], num=100)
curve2 = bezier(verts, t=[0.5, 1.0], num=100)
ax.plot(curve1[:,0], curve1[:,1], lw=3, color="crimson")
ax.plot(curve2[:,0], curve2[:,1], lw=3, ls="--", color="crimson")

plt.show()
```

[image]

As you notice the two curves, i.e. the original arrow and the manually created bezier curve, are not overlaying each other. This is because matplotlib evaluates the Bezier curve in screen space, while the manual version evaluates it in data space.
To obtain the same curve in both cases, we would need to do the evaluation in screen space, which is shown in the following (where we also plot the three bezier nodes, both in data and in pixel space).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from scipy.special import binom

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

kw = dict(arrowstyle = '-', shrinkA = 0, shrinkB = 0, color = 'k', 
          connectionstyle = "arc3, rad = -0.4" )
arrow = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((0, 0), (5, 3), **kw)
ax.add_patch(arrow)
ax.autoscale()
print(arrow.get_path().vertices)

bernstein = lambda n, k, t: binom(n,k)* t**k * (1.-t)**(n-k)

def bezier(points, t=[0,1], num=200):
    N = len(points)
    t = np.linspace(*t, num=num)
    curve = np.zeros((num, 2))
    for i in range(N):
        curve += np.outer(bernstein(N - 1, i, t), points[i])
    return curve

trans = ax.transData
trans_inv = trans.inverted()
verts = trans.transform(arrow.get_path().vertices)
curve1 = trans_inv.transform(bezier(verts, t=[0.0, 0.5], num=100))
curve2 = trans_inv.transform(bezier(verts, t=[0.5, 1.0], num=100))

ax.plot(curve1[:,0], curve1[:,1], lw=3, color="crimson", zorder=0)
ax.plot(curve2[:,0], curve2[:,1], lw=3, ls="--", color="crimson", zorder=0)

from matplotlib.transforms import IdentityTransform
ax.plot(*trans.transform(arrow.get_path().vertices).T, ls="", marker="o", 
        color="C1", ms=7, transform=IdentityTransform())
ax.plot(*arrow.get_path().vertices.T, ls="", marker="o", color="C0", ms=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! Could you elaborate on why the two curves are not exactly the same ? From your previous comment, I thought that using `inv = ax.transData.inverted()` on the vertices would have been sufficient ?

Comment: They would be the same if equal scales were used (i.e. `plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")`). As commented, the difference is that the Bezier is evaluated in screen coordinates by matplotlib, while the manual solution evaluates it in data coordinates.

Comment: Neither adding `plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")` right before `plt.show()` to your answer nor to my code makes the two curves be the same... There is something I do not understand here

Comment: Yep, sorry, that actually requires more: A square axes with equal aspect: `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6));
fig.subplots_adjust(.1,.1,.9,.9);
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")`.

Comment: I updated the answer with a code that hopefully makes this clearer.